# How to use passed arguments with a triple quotes in Big Query with Node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, google-bigquery

I am trying to execute a remote function in Big Query using `@google-cloud/bigquery` npm library.

In the example below, the `dateFrom` and `dateTo` are hard-coded as `2022-06-01T08:00:00.000Z` and `2023-01-01T07:59:59.999Z`, but I want to pass those values from the Node.js side.
I know I can use arguments using a syntax like `@dateFrom`, but no idea how to do it with triple quotes.

Thanks!

```sql
with postgres_things as (
  select
      `remote_function_name`(
        'db_name'
        , """
            select
              name
              , age
              , sex
              , created_at
            from users
            where
              created_at >= ${dateFrom}::timestamptz
              and created_at <= ${dateTo}::timestamptz
          """
        , '{"dateFrom":"2022-06-01T08:00:00.000Z","dateTo":"2023-01-01T07:59:59.999Z"}'
      ) as things
),
.
.
.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand this question, but if you use the back quote to delimit your Javascript strings, then your string can contain any quote or double quote marks you want inside the string and the interpreter will just let them stay as you typed them.  In a regular string, you can always do `\"` or `\'` to escape any quote mark and allow it to be so you could do triple quotes with `\"\"\"`.

Comment: If what you were after is something like Python's triple quote marks (but for use in Javascript), then use a single back quote mark to start and end your string declaration and all other quotes and line breaks inside the string will be just treated as normal characters.